# Solution of Definite integral:$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}}e^{i(k_{1}x+k_{2}y)}dxdy$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to evaluate the following two dimensional integral:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}}e^{i(k_{1}x+k_{2}y)}dxdy$

The paper that i'm following reports the following solution:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}}e^{i(k_{1}x+k_{2}y)}dxdy = \frac{1}{\sqrt{k_{1}^{2}+k_{2}^{2}}}e^{-\sqrt{k_{1}^{2}+k_{2}^{2}}z}$

it might be useful using the following definitions:
$r = \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}$
and
$k = \sqrt{k_{1}^{2}+k_{2}^{2}}$

I think this should follow from some kind of substitution;
anyway i tried to solve it with mathematica but i'm not getting any solution...

Any idea on how to obtain the result shown by the authors?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to switch to polar coordinates.

Comment: do you think that switching to polar coordinates simplifies the integral?

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} = r$ for example.

Comment: yes, however i don't know if the exponential part gets actually simplified adopting polar coordinates...

Comment: That's an indefinite integral

Comment: It may simplify if you introduce $k_1 x + k_2 y = \begin{pmatrix} k_1 \\ k_2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}$. These are just some ideas.

Comment: I'd have to look up more carefully to be sure, but this smells of something where, if one goes to polar coordinates, an integral representation of a (modified?) Bessel function would be useful.

Comment: @Semiclassical I have the same "smell"

Comment: Maybe it helps if you think of your integral as the inverse of the Fouriertransform of the function $f(x,y):=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}^{-1}$. Then maybe you can check your result by Fourier-inversion.

Comment: @frog the integral actually is a definition of a two dimensional fourier transform. The problem is that mathematica don't seem able to solve it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me fill in the details of how to perform the angular integration in tired's answer. First, we can make our lives easier by notating that the integrand $e^{i \mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{x}}$ with $\mathbf{k}=k_1 \hat{x}+k_2\hat{y}=k\hat{k}$ is invariant under rotations about the $z$-axis. So we're free to orient the coordinates such that $\hat{k}$ as the positive $x$-axis i.e. $\mathbf{k}\mapsto k\hat{x}$. Then, defining $s=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, the integral becomes

$$I(k,z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}}}e^{i k x}\,dxdy=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{ik s\cos\theta }}{\sqrt{s^2+z^2}}s\,d\theta \,ds.$$

While this integral hardly seems better, the $\theta$-integral is recognizable to Mathematica in terms of a Bessel function. Indeed, if uses the integral representation $J_n(x)=\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i (n \theta -x\sin \theta)}\,d\theta$ (see eq. 71 on Mathworld's Bessel functions page, or derive by hand using an Jacobi-Anger identity) then the $n=0$ case allows us to write the integration as

$$I(k,z)=2\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{s\,J_0(ks)}{\sqrt{s^2+z^2}}\,ds=\frac{2\pi}{k}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u\,J_0(u)}{\sqrt{u^2+k^2 z^2}}\,du\quad\text{with }u=ks.$$

What remains is to justify the integral identity cited by tired which allows us to conclude $I(k,z)=2\pi k^{-1} e^{-k |z|}.$ I'll see if I can recall the details.

Comment: Mathematica automatically solves the integral:$\frac{2\pi}{k}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u\,J_0(u)}{\sqrt{u^2+k^2 z^2}}\,du$ returning $\frac{1}{k} e^{-kz}$; however i don't know why it is not able to solve the entire integral, I need to pass through a manual subsitution everytime and then perform the last integral with mathematica...

Comment: @user3810266: Try doing "\$Assumptions = k > 0 && z > 0" in order to force it to treat $k$ and $z$ as positive values first, and then call "Integrate[
 Integrate[
  Exp[I k s Sin[\\[Theta]]] s/Sqrt[s^2 + z^2], {\\[Theta], 0, 
   2 \\[Pi]}], {s, 0, \\[Infinity]}]". That should give the integral directly.

Comment: I was already using the first assumptions, however your method still goes through a manual substitution of the variables and therefore of the integration boundaries. I was looking for a completely automated method in which i give a generic function $f(x,y,z)$ and the integration is completely automated... as i have to apply this kind of two dimensional fourier transforms to several functions

Comment: @user3810266: Eh, this isn't even so much a substitution as it is the representation in cylindrical coordinates. That's not terribly labour-intensive to implement. And that's unfortunately about the best I can imagine you can do, since Mathematica is really only suited for doing multivariable integrals one integration at a time (which in Cartesian coordinates is a poor direction for an integral like this.)

Comment: hi just a quick taught, i guess for the second equation (6.554.1) one should take the series representation of $J_0$ and integrate term by term where convergence allows it. Afterwards one can analytically continue safely...

Comment: @tired: That could work, though the concern I had when I thought about it was whether the reciprocal square root would make things overly complicated. (And I'm sure there's more than one way to do things.)

Comment: ok, i'm very excited with what kind of solution you will show up :)

Comment: @Semiclassical: adopting the reference frame used by you is it correct to consider the following equivalence: $y= s \, Sin(\theta)$ and $x= s \, Cos(\theta)$ ? i mean in case i want to consider the integral of another function like $(\frac{x}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}})^{\frac{3}{2}}$

Comment: @user3810266: Indeed so.

Comment: @Semiclassical: Are you sure that it isn't $x= s \, Sin(\theta)$ and $y= s \, Cos(\theta)$ ?because when employing the method that you posted to evaluate the integral of $\frac{x^{2}}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ i get the correct answer (according to the paper that i'm following) only if i consider:$x= s \, Sin(\theta)$ and $y= s \, Cos(\theta)$ and $k_{x}= k \, Sin(\theta)$ and $k_{y}= k \, Cos(\theta)$ otherwise i do not...

Comment: The only way that'd make sense is if $\theta$ isn't the angle relative to the $x$-axis, but that's definitely how I've assumed it in my presentation here. @user3810266

Comment: then I have a question, in the first equivalence that you posted:by substituting $\theta$ and $s$ into  $e^{ikx}$ it becomes $e^{iks Sin(\theta)}$; maybe it is not clear to me, but it looks like you employed $x = s Sin(\theta)$. I think i'm missing something...I'm also noticing that applying the method that you posted i get zero everytime i'm transforming a funcion that has $y$ on the nominator for example $\frac{3xy}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{3/2})}$

Comment: @user3810266: Yep, you're right. Should've put cosine there, which is actually a bit of a pain since the sine version is simpler; defining coordinates in your way would be one simple way to avoid that. I'll think about how best to include that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17898/discussion-between-user3810266-and-semiclassical).

Answer (score 6):

Ok let's see:

Denote the Integral by $I(k_x,k_y,z)$

Going over to Polar coordinates we have:
$x=r\sin(\phi),r\cos(\phi)$, $|det(J)|=r$

\begin{align}
I(k_x,k_y,z)=\int_0^{\infty} dr \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi e^{-ir[k_x sin(\phi)+k_y cos(\phi)]}
\end{align}

It can now be shown that the inner integral equals $2\pi J_0[r\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2}]$

So we are left with (1)
\begin{align}
I(k_x,k_y,z)=2\pi\int_0^{\infty} dr \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}J_0[r\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2}]
\end{align}

Using now Formula 6.554.1 from [Gradstheyn/Ryzhik](http://books.google.de/books?id=ja6kmAEACAAJ&dq=Gradshteyn/Ryzhik&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EyM9VJbVEau5ygPq44L4Bw&redir_esc=y) which states (2)
that $\int_0^{\infty}dq\frac{q}{\sqrt{s^2+q^2}}J_0[qp]=\frac{e^{-sp}}{p}$

We get 
\begin{align}
I(k_x,k_y,z)=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2}}e^{-z\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2}}
\end{align}
which is the stated result apart from a factor of $2\pi$ which supposedly stems from some on of the definitions of Fouriertransform

Unluckily i'm very busy so i can't fill in the proof which leds us to (1) or try to proof (2) so i would appreciate if someone could fill this gaps

Comment: Working on an answer that has those gaps filled in right now (filling in $(1)$ isn't too bad, still working on $(2)$.)

Answer (score 5):

In my first answer, I proceeded by trying to directly compute the momentum integrals. In doing so, I'd forgotten that there is a rather less direct approach which yet has the advantage of not requiring Bessel function identities.

First, note that our task is to take the $2$D Fourier transform of the function $G(\mathbf{r})=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-1/2}=r^{-1}$. My choice of $G$ as symbol for this function is not done idly, for this is in fact the free-space Green's function of the $3$D  Laplacian i.e. $\nabla^2 G(\mathbb{r})=-4\pi \delta^{3}(\mathbf{r})$. This is a standard Dirac-delta identity which can be verified via the divergence theorem and direct differentiation.

The $3$D Fourier transform of this is readily computed to be $(k_x^2+k_y^2+k_z^2)G(\mathbf{k})=4\pi.$ To get the *planar* Fourier transform, we can then take the inverse transform with respect to $k_z$. That iss,

\begin{align}
G(k_x,k_y,z)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}[G(\mathbf{k})](z)
&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i k_z z}G(\mathbf{k})\,dk_z\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2e^{-i k_z z}}{k_x^2+k_y^2+k_z^2}\,dk_z\\
&=\frac{2}{k}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-i k z u}}{1+u^2}\,du
\end{align}
where in the last line I have introduced $k=\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2}$ and $k_z=k u$. This last integral can be evaluated via methods of contour integration (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration#Example_.28II.29_.E2.80.93_Cauchy_distribution) of such) to obtain the desired result

$$\boxed{G(k_x,k_y,z)=2\pi\dfrac{e^{-k |z|}}{k}=2\pi\left(\dfrac{e^{-|z|\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2}}}{\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2}}\right)}$$

Comment: @user3810266: I should point out that these two approaches---direct integration via Bessel functions, and indirect integration via Fourier transforms---are complementary. Either or both may be useful in a given context, and so it's best to understand both.

Comment: is this true for a generic function of $\boldsymbol{r}$? I mean, can I compute the two dimensional fourier transform of $f(\boldsymbol{r})$ by first computing its three dimensional fourier transform and then anti transform along $z$?

Comment: In principle, yes. (There may be exceptional cases, but they don't spring to mind.) It just may not always be the easiest approach; here we had the advantage that taking $3+1$ Fourier transforms was easier than just $2$ since the first three were immediate. @user3810266